# Ccorect values folder not getting selected in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I thought I had this device density/size thing down, but apparently that is not the case.  I have created a new hardware definition within Android Studio using the following dimensions and size.

9.7"
768 x 1024

This results in an ldpi device, which is what I am after.  This was mirrored off of the HP Touchpad device.

I am using several dimens files within my application which are contained within their associated values folder with 2 resource qualifiers each.  A typical values folder in my app looks like this.

values-sw320dp-xhdpi

Using the information above, I believe this should result in the system looking for the dimens file in my values folder shown below.

values-sw480dp-ldpi

I arrived at this conclusion by taking the pixel dimensions of 768 x 1024 and multiplying them by .75 which would result in a with and height in dp of 576 x 768. Since the smallest width is 576, this should use the values folder referenced above of values-sw480dp-ldpi.

I know that it is not using the values specified in this dimens file because the value shown in the layout is from one of my other values folder/dimens files.  Additionally, it is not actually using the values from the file that the layout is referencing either, as changes to that dimens file have no impact on the layout.  It simply is stopping on the first one seen (or something) but not actually using the value.  I have encountered this situation many times and the issue is always fixed by getting the "correct" values folder defined with the appropriate resource qualifiers.  The issue here is that I don't know what the system is actually trying to use and it clearly is not coming up with the same calculations I am.

Here is a screen shot of the device I have build in Android Studio.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Android supports combination of qualifiers in defined order of priority. [Here in Table 2.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) you can see this list.

And [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch) you have fine description of how Android finds the best-matching resources.

---

Also, I wonder what is the reason you create `values` folders with *Screen pixel density (dpi)* qualifiers. I could be wrong, but I think that density matters only with `drawables`/`mipmaps` etc.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I am aware of the information you provided in the above links and am specifying my qualifiers in the order as described in the table.  I will review the information in the doc for how Android finds a best match and see if that highlights anything.  As far as the density qualifier applying to values folders, I believe that it does.

Comment: I am fairly confident that the density qualifiers apply to the values folders as well, as I've had to create several different ones in order to ensure views were positioned where I wanted them to be given different devices I've tested against.  Possibly I am doing something incorrectly or there are better ways I have not learned about yet, but utilizing a combination of smallest width and density has worked for me up to this point, excluding the most recent example I called out in my original post, which is not using the resource I'd expect.